# Proving a union by using the laws of algebra of sets and a new operator

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I am given a new opeator A * B = complement of (A intersect B).  I apologize for not being able to post this with the correct syntax.

Using this new operator, I am to prove, algebraically, that the following is true:

(A * A) * (B * B) = A U B

I've gotten this far:

[image]

2nd part:

[image]

Comment: It's better do not use an image, or at least rotate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there! Remember De Morgan's Law:

$${\overline {A\cap B}}={\overline {A}}\cup {\overline {B}}$$

I will use two different notations for complement so you can see it better in the next line. Continuing from what you had,

$$\overline{A} * \overline{B} = \overline{(\overline{A} \cap \overline{B})} = \overline{A^c} \cup \overline{B^c}$$

Note that the complement of the complement of a set is just that set ($\overline{A^c} = A$) and hence you have:

$$(A * A) * (B * B) = A \cup B$$
Let me know if you need further explanation!

Comment: Thanx man.  So I'm kinda stuck on the 2nd part.  I have (A * B ) * (A * B ) = A intersect B and so far I got to: Complement(A intersect B) * Complement(A intersect B) = Complement(Complement(A intersect B) intersect Complement(A intersect B).)

Comment: Check the post edit

Comment: Use the same law as above. To avoid notational difficulties, I would recommend letting $C = A \cap B$. Then you get: $$(A * B) * (A * B) = \overline{C} * \overline{C} = \overline{\overline{C} \cap \overline{C}} = \overline{\overline{C}} \cup \overline{\overline{C}} = C \cup C = C = A \cap B$$

Answer (score 0):

The exercice mainly aims at testing your knowledge of (1) idempotency of the intersection operation and of  (2) De Morgan's law for sets.

Note : here I use  " X' "  to denote the complement of a set X and the symbol " X ''  " to denote the complement of the complement of X

x belongs to (A*A) * (B * B)

is equivalent to

(1) x belongs to [ (A * A) Inter (B * B)]'

(2) x belongs to [ (A Inter A)' Inter (B Inter B)' ] '

(3) x belongs to [      A '     Inter      B'      ]'

(4) x belongs to        A ''      Union    B ''

(5) x belongs to        A         Union    B

Reasons

For (1) : definition of the * operator

For (2) : again, definition of the * operator

For (3) : idempotency of the Intersection operation ( for all X, X Inter X = X)

For (4) : De Morgan's law for sets ( The complement of X Inter Y is X' Union Y')

For (5) : law of involution ( the complement of the complement of X is X itself)